# Accessing a value from the outer scope when a local member with the same name is present

Tags: scala

Say I have a trait with a property `a`:

```
trait TheTrait {
  def a: String
}
```

I have a class with a property `a` too in which I want to instantiate that trait anonymously:

```
class TheClass {
  val a = "abc"
  val traitInstance = new TheTrait {
    def a = a   // I want to assign it to the `a` of TheClass here
                // but this way it doesn't work
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

either `TheClass.this.a`, or give an alias to `this` in `TheClass` (calling it `self` is customary)

```
class TheClass { self => 
  val a = "abc"
  val traitInstance = new TheTrait {
    def a = self.a   
  }
}
```

Comment: This works when the outer member belongs to a class or trait. I guess there is no way to escape the scope if I wish 'a' to refer to a value introduced within a function block? Just rename those values.

Comment: `self` seems better than `TheClass.this`. Which is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

If the outer vals/vars are within a function block, a way to get past the problem is to wrap them in an anonymous class, giving them a specific name. s.a.

```
val a=1
val c = new { val a=a }    // does not compile

val s = new { val a=1 }
val c = new { val a=s.a }  // compiles :)
```

Of course also just using different names would do the trick, but there are cases where that means prefixing/postfixing with _ $ etc. This is an alternative for those.